# How do I delete an accepted answer?

Tags: support

Im convinced an answer of mine is incorrect, or at least, not as correct as some other answers. I wish to delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention and explain the situation. You cannot delete it yourself.